# println _ in Scala: Why is the type () => Unit instead of (Any) => Unit?

Tags: function, scala

For example, I want to assign the function `println` to a variable `k`

```
scala> val k = println _
k: () => Unit = <function0>
```

I expect the type of k is `(Any) => Unit` but its actual type is `() => Unit`. When I call `k` with an argumnent, it has an error:

```
scala> k(3)
<console>:9: error: too many arguments for method apply: ()Unit in trait Function0
              k(3)
               ^
```

However, calling `printlin` with that argument works well:

```
scala> println(3)
3
```

Does anyone have ideas about assigning the function object `println` to a variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why `println _` is of type `() => Unit` is because there exists an overloaded definition of `println` that doesn't take any parameters ([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L309)):

```
def println() = Console.println()
```

In order to use the `println` that takes a parameter, you have to explicitly tell the compiler to choose it:

```
scala> val k = println(_: Any)
k: Any => Unit = <function1>

scala> k(3)
3
```

Another solution is to use a type ascription:

```
scala> val k: Any => Unit = println
k: Any => Unit = <function1>

scala> k(3)
3
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question, is it possible to assign the two overloaded version println to One varaible?

Comment: @Firegun No (that would lead to the type erasure problem for functions)